# How to test rest api expecting receive an object?

Tags: express, jestjs, supertest

I'm learning tests and using :

- **Express**
- **Jest**
- **SuperTest**
- **Sequelize**

This is user.test.js, Everytime I ran the test, it create a user object in database, in app.get("/"),I have a:

```
User.findAll({});
```

so I would like to test someting more "generic" like a User Object,  its possible, what do you suggest me?

```
const app = require("../app");
const request = require("supertest");
const { User } = require("../models/");
const db = require("../models");

describe('User Model', () => {

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const user = await db.User.create({ name: "Paulo", email: "blablblalbalbal@gmail.com", password: "123mudar" });
        return user

    })

    it('List User', async () => {

        const res = await request(app).get("/");

        expect(res.body).toBe(user);
        expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mock your calls to DB or anywhere outside of your testing area.